# Exit server after 30 seconds idle waiting on accept method

Tags: c++, sockets, server

I have the code:

```cpp
int client_fd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, &len);
```

The server waits at this line. I want to exit the server if there is no incoming connection request for 30 seconds. How to achieve that?

The below code basically waits for incoming requests from client and does some processing. But most of it may be useless to what we are discussing the timeout thing. Probably only the part above the accept method matters.

Pasting the full code here for clarity:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>   
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <iostream> 
#include <map>
using namespace std; 

void Trans( int n );
char* getEpochTime(char* epochTime);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char epochTime[20];
    char startEpochTime[20];
    strcpy(startEpochTime, getEpochTime(startEpochTime));
    bool epochFlag = false;
    char endEpochTime[20];
    strcpy(endEpochTime, getEpochTime(endEpochTime));
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int transactionNumber=0;
    std::map<std::string, int> summaryMap; 
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, // an Internet socket
                    SOCK_STREAM, // reliable stream-like socket
                    0); // OS determine the protocol (TCP)

    if (fd < 0)
        return 1; // something went wrong

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    fd_set  readfds;

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &readfds);

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    // setup server address
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port); // port

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) // bind socket to the server address
        return 1;
    
    if (listen(fd, 1) < 0) // wait for clients, only 1 is allowed.
        return 1;
    printf("Using port %d\n",port);

    while(1) {

        struct sockaddr_in client_address; // client address
        socklen_t clientLen;

        clientLen = sizeof(client_address); 
        int client_fd;
        if (select(fd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) > 0)
        {
            client_fd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, &clientLen);  // accept connection
        }
        else {
            break;
        }

        if (client_fd < 0) // bad connection
            continue; // discard

        char buffer[1024];
        int count = 0;
        count = read(client_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        char hostname[30];
        if(count > 0) {
            transactionNumber++;
            buffer[count] = '\0';
            char *pt;
            pt = strtok (buffer,",");
            char message[10];
            strcpy(message,pt);
            printf("%s\n", message);
            pt = strtok (NULL,",");
            char epoch[20];
            strcpy(epoch,pt);
            pt = strtok (NULL,",");
            strcpy(hostname,pt);
            summaryMap[hostname]++; 
            if(!epochFlag) {
                strcpy(startEpochTime,epoch);
                epochFlag=true;
            }
            printf("%s: # %d (%s) from %s\n",epoch,transactionNumber, message, hostname);
            int transactionExecutionLength;
            sscanf(message+1,"%d", &transactionExecutionLength);
            Trans(transactionExecutionLength);
        }
        char clientMessage[50];
        char _epochTime[50];
        strcpy(_epochTime, getEpochTime(_epochTime));
        sprintf(clientMessage,"%d,%s",transactionNumber,_epochTime);
        write(client_fd, clientMessage, sizeof(clientMessage)); 
        printf("%s: # %d (Done) from %s\n",_epochTime,transactionNumber, hostname);
        stpcpy(endEpochTime,_epochTime);
    }
    map<string, int>::iterator it;
    for ( it = summaryMap.begin(); it != summaryMap.end(); it++ )
    {
        std::cout << it->first  // string (key)
                  << ':'
                  << it->second   // string's value 
                  << std::endl ;
    }

    double startTime = std::stod(startEpochTime);
    double endTime = std::stod(endEpochTime);
    double TotalTime = endTime - startTime;
    return 0;
} 

char* getEpochTime(char* epochTime){
    struct timeval current_time;
    gettimeofday(&current_time, NULL);
    char epochTimeMilli[100];
    char partialSeconds[10];
    sprintf(epochTimeMilli, "%ld", current_time.tv_sec); 
    sprintf(partialSeconds, ".%d", (int)(current_time.tv_usec/10000));    
    strcat(epochTimeMilli, partialSeconds);
    epochTime = epochTimeMilli;
    return epochTime;
}

void Trans( int n ) {
    int TransSave = 0;
    long i, j;

    // Use CPU cycles 
    j = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < n * 100000; i++ ) {
        j += i ^ (i+1) % (i+n);
    }
    TransSave += j;
    TransSave &= 0xff;
}
```

Comment: the posted code contains a mix of C and C++ code.  The result is a C++ program.  I changed the 'tags' to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accept()` does not provide any timeout capability.  Use `select()` or `(e)poll()` beforehand to detect when a listening socket is in a readable state indicating it has an inbound connection waiting to be accepted.  Those functions provide timeouts.  For example:

```c
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

fd_set readfds;

FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(fd, &readfds);

struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 30;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

if (select(fd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) > 0)
{
    len = sizeof(client_address);
    int client_fd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, &len);
    ...
}
else
{
    // do something else...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but the listining socket that is the server accept method will always be in readable state right? My code is inside a while(1) loop and so it waits on accept method

Comment: A listening socket is in a readable state only when it has pending connection(s) waiting to be accepted. Otherwise the readable state is cleared. If the listening socket is in blocking mode (the default), `accept()` will block the caller waiting until a pending connection is available. If the socket is in non-blocking mode, `accept()` will either succeed immediately or it will fail with `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN`. Either way, you need `select()`/`(e)poll()` if you want timeout handling.

Comment: Will your above code work directly if i use it. Or if you could provide some links etc to understand this thing better

Comment: Hmm it does terminate in 30 secs but with some error terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod

Comment: Then you did something else wrong. There is nothing in the code I provided that can throw `std::invalid_argugent` (you tagged the question as C, so I gave you C code, and C has no concept of exceptions. `std::invalid_argument` is C++ only). Besides, the error message clearly shows that the exception is coming from `stod()` being passed an invalid string value that can't be parsed into a `double`. There is no `stod()` in the code I gave you.

Comment: yes there was a bug in my code. One last thing. I think its timing out after 30 seconds even if the server gets a request. So what i wanted was to timeout only if server is idle for 30 seconds. So if a new request comes and code moves ahead from accept method then again the server will wait for 30 seconds before timeout

Comment: "*I think its timing out after 30 seconds even if the server gets a request*" - that is not how it should be working. So you are likely still be doing something wrong. Please edit your question to show your updated code. "*So what i wanted was ...*" - that is exactly how it should work when used correctly. As soon as the listening socket receives a new connection, it will enter a readable state, satisfying the wait so it exits before the timeout expires, and then a subsequent `accept()` will return success without blocking.

Comment: Note that for this code to work correctly, you need to set the socket non-blocking and you need to handle an EWOULDBLOCK error on the call to `accept`. Otherwise, you have a race condition if the incoming connection closes without error in-between when `select` returns and when `accept` is called and the code may wait in `accept` forever. Using `alarm` may be simpler than using `select` or `poll` because of this complication.

Comment: Have updated the whole code. It seems big. But the part where the focus is small. I am only interested in the timeout thing after the server is idle for say 30 seconds. that is there is no incoming request

Comment: @pensee you are not resetting the `fd_set` or `timeval` structs on *every* call to `select()`. Had you read the documentation for `select()`, you would know that `select()` *modifies* those parameters, so you have to reset them each time (using `(e)poll()` instead would avoid that). If anything, instead of waiting the full 30 seconds, this mistake should be causing `select()` to timeout with shorter and shorter intervals on each loop iteration

Comment: @pensee there are quite a lot of other mistakes in this code, too, but they are not relevant to the `accept()` timeout issue.  But why are you mixing C and C++ together like this? You really shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: yes resetting works thanks. I was initially coding with C. But then realized had to use maps and other stuffs so started including c++. was finding it difficult to do things in C
Can you just point out the mistakes. I will try to resolve them myself.